# Get subdomain value in laravel 5.3

Tags: php, laravel, routes, frameworks, subdomain

I am new in laravel, I am creating a subdomain in same project main domain localhost.vibrant-invitations.com and subdomain sadmin.localhost.vibrant-invitations.com on local, now I want to get subdomain value like `sadmin`. I am trying following the code

```
Route::group(['domain' => '{subdomain}.localhost.vibrant-invitations.com'], function () {
    Route::get('/', function ($subdomain) {

        $name = DB::table('users')->where('name', $subdomain)->get();

        dd($name);

    });
});

Route::get('/', function () {
    return "This will respond to all other '/' requests.";
});
```

this is always returning "This will respond to all other '/' requests", Route group with a domain is not working.

My `laravel version 5.3`

Please help me to solve this.

Regards
Yash